# Is having a Goal for each Funnel step a good practice?

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

A little background, I've inherited a problem with Goal/Funnel without a lot of experience with either, but with a bit with Google Analytics in general.

The basic problem is that the goal flow is not working as "the business" expects.

Currently, there are 6 Goals/Funnels. Each set up as a continuation of the previous. E.g.

- Goal 1: RegEx match. No funnel.
- Goal 2: New Regex Match

  - Funnel : Regex from Goal 1, Required
- Goal 3: New regex Match

  - Funnel Step 1: Regex from Goal 1, Required
  - Funnel Step 2: Regex from Goal 2

.... Other goals removed for brevity.

- Goal 6: New Regex Match

  - Funnel Step 1: Regex from Goal 1, Required
  - Funnel Step 2: Regex from Goal 2
  - Funnel Step 3: Regex from Goal 3
  - Funnel Step 4: Regex from Goal 4
  - Funnel Step 5: Regex from Goal 5

From my reading of several tutorials today, they all demonstrate setting up a single Goal/Funnel.

It this setup likely to cause issues or are there advantages to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics has a limit of 20 goals per view.  If you are using six of those at a time, that means that you can only create three funnels.

It is usually best to put the goal as the last step in the funnel.